# Angular, limit sub repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to limit a sub repeat by the index of its parent repeat. So whaever level index it on it will be limited to that (+ 1 so we dont start at 0). Here is my thinking -

```
        <div class="inputRepeater" ng-repeat="face in inputFaces" ng-show="face.isCurrent" >
            <div class="trialGrid">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in rowCollection[0]">{{key}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | limitTo: face.$index + 1">
                        <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

So the tr inside the table would be limited to the initial repeat of face, buy faces $index +  1. This is not working. Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to save a reference to the upper $index

```
    <div class="inputRepeater" ng-repeat="face in inputFaces" ng-show="face.isCurrent" >
        <div class="trialGrid" ng-init="$faceIndex = $index">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in rowCollection[0]">{{key}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | limitTo: $faceIndex + 1">
                    <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `face.$index` use `$parent.$index` because you want to refer parent ng-repeat $index.
Because ng-repeat creates an isolated scope from its current running scope.

**CODE**

```
<div class="inputRepeater" ng-repeat="face in inputFaces" ng-show="face.isCurrent">
    <div class="trialGrid">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in rowCollection[0]">{{key}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection | limitTo: $parent.$index + 1">
                    <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this would be helpful to you.